# how to extract exact value from xml file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

i have this below sample file with more than 1000 entry. I want to extract the session id.
Sample output should be `sessionId="1308130606029610103"`.

```
<cdr-data>
    <cdr>
        <networkInfo payer="830459" payerType="0" pdpAddress="2" pdpType="0"
                     ratingGroup="2" redirectionCode="0" requestType="1006"
                     sequenceNumber="12" serviceIdentifier="0"
                     sessionId="1308130606029610103" sgsnAddress=""
                     sgsnMccMnc="" specialLocationClassId="0" spendControlId="0"
                     tariffToken="0" timeZone="" unitType="2"/>

    </cdr>
    <cdr-data>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. As the question stands it seems like you want people to do the work for you and provide you with code. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Last tag <cdr-data> must be closed?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standard Unix tool for XML processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `grep`:

```
grep -Po "sessionId=[^\s]*" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) lets you run XPath expressions from teh command line. Something like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/cdr-data/cdr/networkInfo/@sessionId" yourfile.xml
```